# Puppet: Is there a way to skip module run based on a facter value

Tags: puppet

I am trying to skip a module run on some nodes which doesn't have a facter value, say "FACTER_dev_boxes=true". how to do that using a conditional statement in init.pp?

Appreciate your suggestion on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, here is [a guide to conditionals](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_conditional.html)

Additionally, facts discovered by facter are provided as [top-level scope variables in Puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_variables.html#facts-and-built-in-variables)

So something simple the following should work:

```
if $dev_boxes == 'true' {
    // Run your module
}
```

Comment: Thanks @xiankai! I know this solves the problem, since I have a very long code block which has to be included into this condition.. I was looking for an alternate, something like a "break" statement. But it seems there is no such option. Thanks again!